# Control process priority using group policy?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

Is it possible to prevent users from changing process priority using group policy? The best I can find is to block users from accessing task manager.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the StartProcess behaviour, not the Scheduler itself. You can, for example, allow the Administrators as the only account for controlling process **starting** scheduling priorities.

This is done here:

```
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment
```

[Increase scheduling priority](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221960(v=ws.11).aspx)

This policy setting determines which user accounts can increase the **base priority** class of a process. It is not a privileged operation to increase relative priority within a priority class.

Specifically, this security setting determines which accounts can use a process with Write Property access to another process to increase the run priority that is assigned to the other process. *A user with this privilege can still change the scheduling priority of a process through the Task Manager user interface.*
Or shorter: A User can do with his User Process whatever he wants.